# TextOut() and the Cambria Math font

Tags: windows, winapi

The Cambria Math font has UNICODE characters beyond `0xFFFF`. You can see them in a Word document, just by inserting a Symbol and selecting the Cambria Math font. By the way, the Windows Character Map does not show these characters. My question is : how to exhibit those UNICODE characters in a Windows app using `TextOut()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display these supplementary code points you need to use UTF-16 [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates).

A surrogate pair is a way of representing single code points beyond `0xFFFF` as two wide characters.  You simply pass a surrogate pair to `TextOut()` and it will be displayed.

Comment: @David You mean to say that the character string passed to TextOut() is made of two WCHARS containing the high and the low surrogates and they will be interpreted automatically by TextOut() as UTF_16 encoding for one UNICODE char ? If this is so, how to obtain the surrogate pairs, for example, for the code 0x1D400 ? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Look up code points on the web. For example: http://graphemica.com/%F0%9D%90%80  and you want the UTF-16LE encoding: 0x35D8 0x00DC

Comment: Ok, but if you apply the formula given in [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates) you don't get 0x1D400.

Comment: did you try reversing the two input chars. Perhaps formula is big endian.

Comment: @David If you apply the formula with H = 0xD835 and L = 0xDC00 you get 0x1D400. I'm marking your answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: That's just an endianness thing.